# Every file in the remote repository is staged for deletion

Tags: git

My development machine has a standard `git` repository (i.e. with a work directory). After changes are committed, they are pushed to a remote bare repository on my production server where a `post-receive` hook deploys the changes to a work directory. I also push these commits to a second backup remote bare repository on yet a different server.

I went to the production server and ran a `git status` command with `--git-dir` pointing to my bare repository and `--work-tree` pointing to my deployment directory. It showed every file within every sub-directory of my deployment directory staged for deletion and these same sub-directories as containing untracked files. A `git log` command shows that all the commits are present and a `git status` from my local machine shows that I am "up to date with origin/master." I also verified that a `git show HEAD:file1` yields the same contents as file `file1` in the deployment directory.

I then went to my backup remote repository and cloned a bare repository on my local development machine from that. I then ran a `git status` with `--git-dir` pointing to my newly cloned bare repository and `--work-tree` pointing to my development work directory and got the same results, i.e. that all the files were staged for deletion.

To further complicate matters I have a second project also with a remote bare repository on a different production server and deployment work directory and a second backup remote bare repository. This time when I do a `git status` on the production server, instead of showing all the files staged for deletion, it shows that for a few files there have been changes staged for commit but since then the files have been changed but not added. The changes that have been staged for commit seem to be the `HEAD~1` versions and the files that have been "changed but not added" are the `HEAD` versions. If I were to execute a `git checkout -f` command, I believe I would end up with the `HEAD~1` versions in the work directory and that would not be good. Yet when I restored the backup bare repository and did a `git status` command, it then showed every file staged for deletion.

**Can somebody explain what might have happened to have caused this?** Here is *one* of my concerns: The `post-receive` hook that I use on my production server is not implemented as many are by executing a `git checkout -f` command but rather something more complicated. The reason for this has to do with having been forced to use a symbolic link for a directory. But I may be able to get away from using the symbolic link and would like to use the simpler `git checkout -f` method for my hook. But in general `get checkout -f` will not replace the work directory contents with the `HEAD` version if there are staged changes. At first I thought there was something my `post-receive` hook might have done that could have explained this problem. But it cannot explain seeing the same behavior using a clone of the backup repository (there are no hooks involved) used with my own local work directory.

My local version of `git` is `git version 2.17.1.windows.2` and the remote server versions are `git version 2.19.1`.

**Update**

I have updated my local `git` version to `git version 2.24.1.windows.2`. I then created a new bare remote repository on my backup `git` repository and then did ...

```
git remote add origin3 url-to-new-repository
git push -u origin3  --all
```

... in order to create a new, fresh repository (my local repository had nothing staged at the time and was shown to be in sync with my production server's remote repository).

I then went to my production server and cloned a bare repository from this newly created backup repository and repeated the `git status` using this new cloned repository and it still showed all the files (as far as I can tell) staged for deletion. How can this be when the files exist?

**Clarifications**

1. I have never run a `git --git-dir=git-repository-directory --work-tree=work-directory` command specifying *different* directories for the same `git` repository.
2. I have verified that if I newly clone a repository with a `git clone --bare` command that the resulting repository is missing the `index` file. If I then rebuild the index with a `git reset` command, the `git status` produces the expected results. I have no reason not to assume that the current remote repository, which is missing the `index` file, was not created without it to begin with also. There is the other repository that does have an index file which has a few discrepancies that cannot be so easily explained.
3. I do not currently deploy changes to the aforementioned repositories by using a `post-receive` hook that uses the `git checkout -f` technique (which clearly would not work in these cases until the index is repaired). The reason is that the actual work directory contains some symbolic links out of necessity which `git` cannot handle (and in truth I have omitted the expected errors that these symbolic links generate when testing the `git status` command). My actual `post-receive` hook is based on issuing a `git diff --name-status --find-renames=100% from-revision to-revision` command and analyzing the returned results. After analyzing the changes, the only `git` facility I use for effecting the updates is a `git archive` command to extract from the repository the latest revisions of files that need to be updated in the work directory. I then issue whatever file and directory rename/move/delete commands are needed and the `tar`command against the git-created archive if files have been updated. It is very complicated code but seems to work (so far). But if I can get rid of the symbolic links and and use a hook that uses `git checkout -f` for deployment, I would much prefer that. I have only so far taken a cursory look at https://gitolite.com/deploy.html, but nothing there has dissuaded me from that route. I have used this technique successfully for several other repositories.

Comment: try `git reset --mixed` first.

Comment: @Serge Thanks, but I am not so much looking for a way to undo the situation as I am trying to understand how it came about to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

The root of the problem is that you are trying to use Git as a deployment system as well as a version control system.  As a deployment system, Git leaves a lot to be desired.  (Well, some might say that about it as a VCS too, but... :-) )

- In my opinion, using Git as a deployment tool is a mistake.  The big danger here is not that it doesn't work, but rather that it *almost* works.
- For another opinion (the other guy thinks it's OK in the end, with many caveats), see https://gitolite.com/deploy.html.
- Note that Heroku and Ruby on Rails provide their own deployment wrappers (which I have never used), and various CI/CD systems have deployment tools and/or wrappers.  Python comes with `pip`, which is better than nothing, but still has some issues: see, e.g., https://www.nylas.com/blog/packaging-deploying-python/.  See https://stackify.com/top-deployment-tools-2018/ for a slightly out of date (2018) list of various deployment tools.

#### Lots of detail

[Serge's comment/suggestion of `git reset --mixed`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59490026/every-file-in-the-remote-repository-is-staged-for-deletion#comment105155406_59490026) should actually "fix" the issue, but as you note it might well recur.

All I can say for sure, not having all your code for viewing and testing, is this: when you run:

```
git --git-dir=<path1> --work-tree=<path2> status
```

or:

```
GIT_DIR=<path1> GIT_WORK_TREE=<path2> status
```

the `git status` command is going to compare these three items against each other:

1. the `HEAD` commit in the specified Git dir;
2. the index—that's *the*, single, one, primary index—in the specified Git dir;
3. the specified work-tree

You're seeing "staged for delete".  Any time you see "changes staged for commit", this means that in comparing item #1 with item #2, Git sees that the `HEAD` commit *does* have these files, and the index *does not* have these files.  Exactly what removed those files from the index—and maybe put any other files, ones that you don't want to be in the index, into the index—well, who can say?

If you see changes "not staged for commit", that means that when comparing item #2—the index for the Git directory—to item #3, your chosen work-tree, that means that what's in the index does not match what is in the work-tree.

It's quite likely that by abusing Git as a deployment tool, you're causing the (single) index to be overwritten at various points by the (multiple, different) deployments to (multiple, different) work-trees.<sup>1</sup>

**Again, the real root of the problem is that Git is not a deployment tool in the first place.**  But we can see from the description so far that this will happen any time you attempt to use the (single) index to describe multiple *different* work-trees.

Note that the version of Git on your laptop is entirely irrelevant.  The issue is that on the server, you're running Git commands, using the bare repository as the repository.  As you do this, you *temporarily* (for one Git command) give that bare repository a work-tree.  Its (single) index is now used, for that one Git command, to index the work-tree.  Then, at some point, you run another Git command, with the same repository, but a *different* work-tree.  That (single) index is now being used for the other work-tree.

The index in a bare repository is somewhat vestigial.  It does exist, so you *can* use Git as a deployment tool like this, but if you are going to do that, you *must* use *one index per temporarily-instantiated work-tree*.  To do that, set `GIT_INDEX_FILE` in the environment, per work-tree.  Or, since the primary function of the index is to be used for making *new* commits, and Git will rebuild it automatically if it's removed, you can *remove* it—knowing that it lives in `$GIT_DIR/index`—and reset, but if you do this, you're setting things up for terrible failure modes if and when two deployments try to run simultaneously.

---

<sup>1</sup>When using `git worktree add`, which requires Git 2.15 or later to be really stable—it has a bad bug in earlier versions—Git creates a new index for each added work-tree.  In theory, adding work-trees to a bare repository might be one way to make Git work rather better as a deployment tool.  But Git still isn't *actually* a deployment tool, so this is analogous to discovering that some screwdrivers work better as chisels than do other screwdrivers.  Sure, that particular flat-bladed screwdriver doesn't explode in your hand nearly as often as those other ones you were using a moment ago, but it's still not *designed* to be used that way.

Comment: So my understanding of `git` seems to be woefully incomplete. According to what I have read, "The git index is where you place files you want committed to the git repository." Based on that I have been assuming that after cloning a bare repository to which only pushes have been done, that the index should be empty. Your description of the index, if I am reading it correctly, seems to be in conflict with this. So, I need to do a bit more research. BTW, Google "git post-receive hook to deploy" and you will get lots of hits that use `git checkout -f` to deploy. (more...)

Comment: Yes, the index is a complicated little beastie. It has multiple roles: it's where you build a new commit ("staging area"), but it's also where you do merges (no special name for this), and it also enables Git to avoid touching the file system ( "index") so as to go fast ("cache"). Unfortunately, `git checkout -f` *almost* works as a cheap and sleazy deployment system, in the same way that a flat-bladed screwdriver *almost* works as a chisel. :-)

Comment: I have used the `git checkout -f` technique on one project from the very beginning and I went in and did a `git status` and it showed no issues, i.e. "nothing added to commit but untracked files present", and those files listed as untracked were indeed correctly reported.

Comment: And for what it's worth, for the repository that shows all the files deleted when doing a `git status`,  under the `git` directory there is no file named `index`. I also believe that when I cloned a new repository from the backup repository, it did not have an `index` file either. The repository that has the other problem, i.e. the `HEAD~1` revisions are staged for a few files while the work directory has the `HEAD` revisions, there is an `index` file (as you would guess).

Comment: When the file doesn't exist, nothing has tried to use it (or—though this is unlikely—something did use it, but carefully removed it afterward). This defeats Git's attempts to use the existing `$GIT_DIR/index` file as a proxy for some work-tree, and thereby enables using Git as a cheap-and-sleazy deployment tool. So you could just keep removing the `index` file after Git creates it. For another opinion, see https://gitolite.com/deploy.html (I'll edit this link into the answer too).

Comment: So I will update my post to clarify some things that may have been misconstrued.

Comment: Interesting. `git archive` should not be creating an index file ... so, what *is* doing it? Check the date-and-time-stamp on the file and see if you can figure out who/what might be running at that time.

Comment: Let me clarify again: In the post-receive hook, if I detect after doing a a `git diff --name-status --find-renames=100% from-revision to-revision` command that file `a/b/c.txt` has been updated, I then execute the equivalent of `git archive --format=tar to-revision a/b/c.txt | tar --warning=no-timestamp -xvhf -`. So the archive, which is just a tar file, is being piped to a `tar` command that immediately extracts the file to the work directory (which has been set to the current directory). There should be nothing that affects the index (the index file is missing, as I have said). (more ...)

Comment: But this technique 1. gets the correct revision from the repository (which is invariably the HEAD revision) and 2. ensures that all the required directories are created if the file is a new file that never existed before and is in a new directory that never existed before.

Comment: I agree that your post-receive hook should not result in the existence of `$GIT_DIR/index`. But you say the file does exist (at least in some cases)—so what is creating it?

Comment: The problem all along has been a *missing* index file, at least in one case. I now believe there should always be an index file. The point of running `git reset` is to correct the contents of or supply a missing index (in the former case you should first backup and delete the original file). The absence of this file was the reason why a status command was showing all those files staged for deletion. When I then did a `git reset`, the index file was created and nothing was any longer staged for deletion The question then was why did the `git clone --bare` not create an index file originally?

Comment: Read point number 2. under **Clarifications** in my edited question. I think this has been *the* issue all along. There is, however, that other repository that *has* an index but when I do a `git status` shows a few files that have a prior revision staged for commit. I have no explanation for this but certainly would know how to fix this.

Comment: Ah: the reason a bare repository doesn't have an initial `index` file is that it has not run `git checkout`. The index is after all intimately tied to the work-tree. That's why it's a little odd that a bare repository (which has no work-tree) has an index. A missing index is never an error: it just means "no files in the index" (i.e., the next commit will have no files in it) and therefore any files in the work-tree are by definition untracked.

Comment: I created a bare repository on my remote server and a new, empty deployment directory. There was no index file for the repository. I created a `post-receive` hook that set `--work-tree` to the deployment directory when running `git checkout -f master`. Locally I created an empty git repository, added a remote definition for the aforementioned remote repository, created a file, added it, committed it, and did a `git push -u remote/master`. The file was neatly added to the remote deployment directory *and* an index file now existed in the remote repository. We agree this is as it should be?

Comment: Yes: the `git checkout` step notices that there's no index, *creates* one by reading the selected commit *into* the index, and updates the (temporarily assigned, for this one command) work-tree based on the fact that each of these files are getting copied into (well, "linked into" by hash ID, analogous to hard links by inode number) the index. The index in the bare repository is now, in effect, tied to that work-tree, even though the Git repository itself, being bare, has no work-tree.

Answer (score 0):

First, deploying changes by having a bare, remote repository on a production server and a `post-receive` hook that executes a `git checkout -f master` command setting the `--work-tree` parameter appropriately seems reasonably reliable (it has been for me where I have been able to use it).

The situations I have been describing have been ones where I have *not* been able to use this method because my directory layout as defined in `git` does not correspond to the actual deployment directory layout for two reasons:

1. A directory was named `www` which in the actual production server is a symbolic link for the real directory `public_html`. This in itself could have been easily remedied by simply renaming my directory. But I had other problems:
2. Two of my `git` repositories were for websites that ended up being parked under the `public_html` directory described in 1. To handle this, I had to define a directory named `work_dir` that contained the top-level directories as defined in my `git` repository for my parked website but were actually symbolic links to the real directories located wherever I chose to put them on the production server.

For these reasons I had to write my own hook that analyzed the the most recent commit and did the deployment. For the repository described in 1. above, which only had one symbolic link, I wanted to see what a `git status` command would generate if I set the `--work-tree` argument to point to the actual deployment work directory (realizing I would get erroneous results because of the `www` symbolic link, which I would ignore). But I discovered that *all* files were being shown as staged for deletion.

That's when I discovered that the `$GIT_DIR/index` file was missing, which explained the above results. And this is what I learned:

When one clones a bare repository there is never an index file; when you do your first push to this repository is when the index file *normally* gets created. In one case, for whatever reason, it has never gotten created and that may have something to do with `--work-tree` pointing to a directory containing nothing but symbolic links. Yet in another case with a similar setup there is an index file. I cannot recall the complete history of the creation of these repositories to explain these discrepancies. But at least I have the answer to my original question as to why files appear to be staged for deletion and I know what to do if I decide for the one repository to rename the `www` directory to `public_html` so I can get away from using my complicated hook.